# Connecting two apartment networks via router (separate internet connections)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

```
PC A1      PC A2                              PC B1      PC B2
  \         /                                   \         /
   Gateway A         ------ Router -----         Gateway B
   |                                             |
   Modem A                                       Modem B
```

Hey guys,

I am trying to figure this one out, and I can't find anything online that would suit my specific situation. Essentially, I live in a duplex and we all consider ourselves one household. However, each side has a different internet connection with the same provider (GCI, Alaska), each with different networks. What I am looking for is a solution to share my media server over both networks at gigabit speeds.

I have thought of the VPN route, but that would cut down on bandwith from the media server to the media client. Since we live right next to each other, it would make more sense anyway to run a long CAT5E to the other side of the house. Also, I only have the budget for a cheaper router (no level 3 smart switch), so I am looking for an easy solution here.

From what I have learned, I need to have both LANs with different address spaces (each provided by a wireless router with their own DHCP) connect to each other via WAN through the switch. This way, we have our own networks that can talk to each other to share resources, yet remain completely independent of each other. If one side were to move out, I would like to not have to completely rebuild my network.

Another thing I was thinking of was if it was possible to set up a VPN without going through the internet... as in VPN from one network to the other via a crossover cable?

I think this is possible, I just need a bit of direction. I hope this all makes sense to you guys. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I just found out my router has the ability to do Dual WANs. Maybe that is the solution?

Comment: If you put a second NIC in the media server you could connect it straight to both LANs (yes they would need to be separate ranges).  No need for a router at all.

Comment: @Paul, you should make that an answer, it is the best one.